# Is there a way to achieve same anonimization through datasets

Tags: r

With given data frames

```
Table1 <- data.frame (ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"), Color = c("Yellow","Pink", "Red"), Classification = c("Furniture", "Vehicle", "RTV"), Zone = c("Europe", "Asia", "America") )
Table2 <-data.frame (ID = c("ID1", "ID2"), Product = c("Product1", "Product2"),Color = c("Pink", "Red"))
Table3 <- data.frame (ID = c("ID2", "ID1", "ID3"), Grade = c("Excellent","Mediocre", "Good"), Classification = c("RTV", "Vehicle", "Furniture"), Zone = c("America", "Asia", "Europe") )
```

Id like to achieve this

[image]

If thats available for one column - can I apply it across all my dataframes, so it anonymize accurately any repetitions of data?

Comment: Which is your reference table? Are the ID unique?

Comment: Lets say Table1, and yes ID supposed to be unique but i think its not the case here as I want to get values have same "hash" values despite its ID(?) so Red will be always HashColor2 regardless of ID but I assume its on purpose of function right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted,

```
table_list <- list(Table1, Table2, Table3)
key <- data.frame(color = c("Yellow", "Pink", "Red"),
                  color_new = c("HashColor1", "HashColor2", "HashColor3"),
                  classification = c("Furniture", "Vehicle", "RTV"),
                  classification_new  = c("HashClass1", "HashClass2", "HashClass3"))

match_replace <- function(x){
  if ("Color" %in% names(x)) {
    x$Color <- key$color_new[match(x$Color, key$color)]
  }
  if ("Classification" %in% names(x)) {
    x$Classification <- key$classification_new[match(x$Classification, key$classification)]
  }
  
  x
}
```

For `Table1`

```
match_replace(Table1)

   ID      Color Classification    Zone
1 ID1 HashColor1     HashClass1  Europe
2 ID2 HashColor2     HashClass2    Asia
3 ID3 HashColor3     HashClass3 America
```

For every table `table_list`,

```
lapply(table_list, match_replace)

[[1]]
   ID      Color Classification    Zone
1 ID1 HashColor1     HashClass1  Europe
2 ID2 HashColor2     HashClass2    Asia
3 ID3 HashColor3     HashClass3 America

[[2]]
   ID  Product      Color
1 ID1 Product1 HashColor2
2 ID2 Product2 HashColor3

[[3]]
   ID     Grade Classification    Zone
1 ID2 Excellent     HashClass3 America
2 ID1  Mediocre     HashClass2    Asia
3 ID3      Good     HashClass1  Europe
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea to the other answer, but does not require that you know all the colors, classifications, zones, etc. and is agnostic to the columns (will anonymize any columns other than ID). Also, uses a true hash (md5).

The basic idea is this: for every column to be anonymized, we need to know all possible values. To do this we create a "master table" by binding together all the tables row-wise, then create the hashes based on the master table, then dis-assemble the master table back to the original format.

```
library(data.table)
library(openssl)
base.tables <- list(T1=Table1, T2=Table2, T3=Table3)
base.cols   <- lapply(base.tables, colnames)
all.tables  <- rbindlist(mapply(\(x, tname) {setDT(x)[, table:=tname]}, base.tables, names(base.tables
                                                                                           )), fill = TRUE)
anonCols    <- setdiff(names(all.tables), c('ID', 'table'))    # columns to anonymize   
all.tables[, c(anonCols):= lapply(.SD, md5), .SDcols=anonCols]
anon.tables <- split(all.tables, all.tables$table)
anon.tables <- mapply(\(x, cols) {x[, cols, with=FALSE]}, anon.tables, base.cols)
base.tables
## $T1
##    ID  Color Classification    Zone
## 1: ID1 Yellow      Furniture  Europe
## 2: ID2   Pink        Vehicle    Asia
## 3: ID3    Red            RTV America
## 
## $T2
##     ID  Product Color
## 1: ID1 Product1  Pink
## 2: ID2 Product2   Red
##
## $T3
##     ID     Grade Classification    Zone
## 1: ID2 Excellent            RTV America
## 2: ID1  Mediocre        Vehicle    Asia
## 3: ID3      Good      Furniture  Europe
anon.tables
## $T1
##     ID                            Color                   Classification                             Zone
## 1: ID1 51e6cd92b6c45f9affdc158ecca2b8b8 bb3a8b2e390142074e49741a0121d623 912d59cdf1d3f551fae21f6f0062258f
## 2: ID2 8dc5344bc0746e1cc5abf896ca03bbdf d6af9c1eaff2a89ebd3f8d0c542be12b 154a67340e8c14dd5253dc4ff6120197
## 3: ID3 ee38e4d5dd68c4e440825018d549cb47 ad2d89100e475427fae2882f2d5dcc36 088f003833d523d9dccc529e929afdc7
##
## $T2
##     ID                          Product                            Color
## 1: ID1 82cbf74569427f33b97d3ffcebba9bab 8dc5344bc0746e1cc5abf896ca03bbdf
## 2: ID2 6b27e2dc9afb06f3e433add532882f70 ee38e4d5dd68c4e440825018d549cb47
##
## $T3
##     ID                            Grade                   Classification                             Zone
## 1: ID2 fcc2d28a33d2df558f18766e067569c6 ad2d89100e475427fae2882f2d5dcc36 088f003833d523d9dccc529e929afdc7
## 2: ID1 d6f4c79f64a33fd9e11c1e46c7ecadde d6af9c1eaff2a89ebd3f8d0c542be12b 154a67340e8c14dd5253dc4ff6120197
## 3: ID3 0c6ad70beb3a7e76c3fc7adab7c46acc bb3a8b2e390142074e49741a0121d623 912d59cdf1d3f551fae21f6f0062258f
```